# How can I create the following shape in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

I am trying to create a following shape in android.

[image]I tried following code but it's only for changing the `corners`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#ffffff" />

<gradient
    android:startColor="#00EBCF"
    android:endColor="#00BEEC"
    android:angle="180"
    android:type="linear" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="80dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="80dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
```

What do I need to make changes in code to achieve the above shape?

## Edit1

As per the answer I used following code (modifications in layout height):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:width="1500dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:top="95dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#36D6E9" />

    </shape>
</item>
```

But when I am using this layout as a `background` for `LinearLayout`. It's showing me this:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/header_shape_rect">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]use this as an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:height="200dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ccc"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:height="200dp" android:top="95dp" android:width="1500dp" >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ccc"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: It says: `Element items must be declared`

Comment: it is a layer-list it is not showing in here i don't know why. wrap the two `items` in `<layer-list>`. I've added a screenshot of the code

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please check out the #Edit1 section my question detail.

Comment: Try adding `android:bottom="-100dp"` to the second item